# cordova barcodescanner plugin the beep sound isn't played on iPad

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I added the barcodescanner  plugin to my phonegap project.

I tried to scan qr codes using my android device in witch the app works perfectly.

But when trying to run my app on my iPad, I can't hear the beep sound.

I searched on the net to found if someone faced that problem, what I found is just how to disable the beep:

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$cordovaBarcodeScanner](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/) is the latest version & works perfectly on iOS & Android!